# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Never>'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

i have tried to turn Future to nullable and also the string but something goes wrong any help please?

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      getName().then((value) {
        print(value);
        throw("error!!!!!");
      }).catchError((error) => print(error.toString()));
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

out side the build method somewhere in my class

```
Future<String> getName() async =>'Some String';
```

Comment: i'm just trying to handle the error in the then () in .catch why it tells me that

Comment: It would help if you tell us in which line the problem is. Copy the whole error message in your question.

Comment: my problem is why can't the catchError handle my exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this fixed my code

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => getName().then((value){
          //  the return type of an error handler is not acceptable
          // as the value of future.
          // after lambda expression is executed it gone so
          // we wouldn't know where the error came from
          // because also the return type is dynamic so we 
          //can't get to a datatype interface so it may be null since it's dynamic 
          if(value is FutureOr) {
            throw("error");
          }
        }).catchError((error) =>  print(error.toString()) ) ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
getName().then((value) {
                print(value);
                throw ("error!!!!");
              }).catchError((error) {
                print("catch error :: " + error.toString());
              });
```

that code print `catch error :: error!!!!`. Is that you want?

Comment: i wanted to catch the then() exception in the .catchError() that's why i throw an exception in the then callback

Comment: didn't work for me unless i made a condition to check if the value FutureOr